# Accessing variables from another Java program

Tags: java, string, jar, directory, transport

I am making a Java program that switches between two `jar`s using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c java -jar fileTwo.jar");
```

But, I need the `class` from one `jar` to somehow transport the `string` values within it to the `class` in the other `jar`. Since the two classes are from different `jar` files, I can't find any methods that can transport `string` between two `jar` directories.

If it helps, I am making a program that allows you to create and access accounts. That is why I need to transport `strings`, so I can store them in a `data` `class` to use as a reference for later logins. I have to use `string` because `char` can not be assigned the value gotten from the method `jtfFirst.getText();` which is a `JTextField`.

Comment: If you need this to be bidirectional, use [sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

Comment: @Sarvadi looking at this five years later (with five more years of experience in Java), I have a much greater appreciation for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let one program write the string into a file and the other read it from the file. You can also pass the string as the command-line parameter to the second program. Say, `s` is the variable with the string. Then you can exec `"cmd /c java -jar fileTwo.jar \""+s+"\"".` (Enclose the string into quotation marks if it consists of more than one word). The string will be available to the second program as `args[1]`.

Comment: You can pass it as an array of Strings. In case of multiple String arguments.

Answer (score 2):

In jar do you have its manifest file ? If its present than export the package from which u need to transport the values of string "s"  and import that package in the manifest file of the jar where you need to use the value of that String "s". All editing will be done in its manifest file. Example :
    For Exporting package use this : Export-Package: PackageFullPath
    For Import that package use this :Import-Package: Package path used in exporting.